# JavaScript Battle Simulator Failing

Tags: javascript, html, prompt

I was attempting to make a battle simulator in which I prompted a user to input the attacking troops, defending troops, as well as kill rates by using the prompt() function in JavaScript. When I wrote the code into an HTML document to test it, it fails to prompt the user. I do realize that I could have written the code a lot better below by using prototypes now, but the idea only came to me after completing the code. I apologize for formatting weirdness in the code below as well. The code I need help debugging is below. Would you be able to help me figure out what is wrong with the code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Battle Simulator AMUN </title>
</head>

<body>  

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
    var armyAttackingIn;
    var armyAttackingNumber;
    var armyDefendingIn;
    var armyDefendingNumber;
    //declares variables
    armyAttackingIn=prompt("How many forces are in the attacking army?");
    armyAttackingNumber = parseInt(armyAttackingIn);
    armyDefendingIn=prompt("How many forces are in the defending army?");
    armyDefendingNumber = parseInt(armyDefendingIn);
    //gets the number of armies

    var morale;
    //makes morale a factor
    var moraleYesOrNo = prompt("Shall morale be a factor? Y/N");
    if (moraleYesOrNo=="Y"||moraleYesOrNo=="Yes"||moraleYesOrNo="yes") {
    morale = ((defender/attacker)*3+.3)*100;
     if (morale>=100) {
        morale = 100;
     }
    }
    else {
    morale = 100;
    };
    //defines what morale is.
    var killRateDefense = parseInt(prompt("Insert the defensive kill rate. Default is 70.","70");)/100;
    var killRateOffense = parseInt(prompt("Insert the offensive kill rate. Default is 60.","60");)/100;
    var battle = function() {
//defines the kill rate
    var armyAttackingLeft = armyAttackingNumber - (armyDefendingNumber*killRateDefense*(100/morale));
    var defendingArmyLeft = armyDefendingNumber - (armyAttackingNumber*killRateOffense*(morale/100));
//gets armies left
    if(armyAttackingLeft<0) {
        armyAttackingLeft = 0
    };
    if(armyDefendingLeft<0) {
        armyDefendinigLeft = 0
    };
    //makes the minimum troops left 0
    }
battle();
document.write("The attacking army was " + armyAttackingIn + "men strong" <br>");
document.write("The defending army was " + armyDefendingIn + "men strong" <br>");
document.write("The morale was " + morale + "/%" <br>);
document.write("The defensive kill rate was " + killRateDefensive + "/% and the offensive kill rate was " + killRateOffensive + "/%" <br>);
document.write("There were " + (armyAttackingNumber-armyAttackingLeft) + " attackers killed" <br>);
document.write("There were " + (armyDefendingNumber-armyDefendingLeft) + " defenders killed" <br>);
document.write("There are " + armyAttackingLeft + " attacking soldiers that survived and there are " + armyDefendingLeft + " defending soldiers that survived.");
if (armyAttackingLeft == 0) {
    document.write(<br>"The attacking force was demolished. Everyone died.");
};
if (armyDefendingLeft == 0) {
    document.write(<br>"The defending force was demolished. Everyone died.");
};
//writes the document


</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.write(<br>` gives a syntax error. And btw don't ever use `document.write` unless it's necessary.

Comment: There's quite a few errors in here. `moraleYesOrNo="yes"` is not a valid logical statement in javascript for a start.

Comment: I don't know if it's your only issue, but it should be `document.write("<br> The...` instead of what you have now. Many other common issues can be found by pressing F12 in your browser to open its Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Javascript Console of your browser before? You may find it a useful debugging tool.

Obvious errors with just the prompt() calls: You have an extra semicolon in your code and that is causing this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list".

The correct line is:

```
parseInt(prompt("Insert the defensive kill rate. Default is 70.","70"))/100;
```

Your if statement is missing an '='. You are currently doing an assignment instead of a check, and it's throwing an error. It should be:

```
if (moraleYesOrNo=="Y"||moraleYesOrNo=="Yes"||moraleYesOrNo=="yes") {
```

There's also a typo in one of your vars:

```
armyDefendinigLeft = 0
```